# Problems with modern fictional mind reading

Tags: science-fiction, mind

The thing is, thoughts and the mind are, from what I believe, only connected, not the same, so why does mind reading in movies and comics and stuff make thoughts the only things known from mind reading?  Wouldn't it be thought reading?  And if it was proper mind reading, what happens with brain signals.  Would it be read and sent to your own body to make what the other persons doing happen to yourself due to your brain processing the signals, or would they be ignored? I need answers, other wise my brain is going to explode...

Comment: Hi and welcome Dalton, Son of John. This site's purpose is to build fictional  worlds. Even though knowing why some mind power are made commonly is helpful in doing that, it's asking about existing worlds (3rd party worlds are off-topic) without the little spark of "building" something which is needed here. A more on-topic question would be asking how to clearly differentiate thought/mind reading powers for a secret organization of a fantasy world you're making :).

Comment: Also, I feel like you're a bit confused with all the mind and thoughts words. Well, at least I am x). It would be good to define what is "mind" in this context (and perhaps even "thoughts"). Indeed, those are linked to both philosophy and religion : you have [wide and varied descriptions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind) of what people are/think ^^".

Comment: There's a whole class of story-writing tools that fall into this category: time travel, super powers, magic, telekinesis, telepathy.... My favorite is pyrokinesis. None of these are real, but it's surprising how many people want them treated as if they were real and everybody's keeping the science behind them a secret. The truth is, your world, your rules. We're here to help you develop those rules. So, how do you think telepathy should work on your world?

Answer (score 5):

Mind reading is fictional. It works however the author wants. In films it works in whatever way the writers think will make it a better film. Films can only give you pictures and images. So the films do not have people getting smells or sensations from their mind reading

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do mind-reading in your fiction, you have to come up with a model based on an existing phenomena.

Surface telepathy is often based on audio telecommunications because that's what we're familiar with. The strong (disproven) Sapir-Whorf hypothesis says we can't have thoughts unless we have words to put them into. This is nonsense, but it demonstrates a perspective that both writers and audiences can attach to.

IMHO, this is the lazy writer's way of portraying telepathy. If we have that, we should also be able to send pictures, smells, emotional reactions, etc., but those are harder to imagine, thus harder to write.

More realistic would be perceptual bleed-through, where you have difficulty telling what your feelings and thoughts are, and what perceptions belong to other people. This is more of a synesthesia model.

Another way that they portray mind reading is like a [TEMPEST attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename)), where you pick up on the electromagnetic impulses of other peoples' brains and rebuild the thoughts that the person has based on that.

Further down the list is invasive brain scans. Honestly, we don't even understand how memories are stored, much less how someone would be able to dig into memories, so you're on your own there. Maybe they work like MRI's? Dunno.